# Object exported as Obj looses textures in Unity

Tags: texturing, uv, export, import

So I recently got into blender/unity in order to create 3D Models. I'm still learning the ropes and have started to run into some issues that I'm unsure how to fix.

Here's what's going on. I have a model that I imported into Blender that I ripped off an N64 Game (Banjo Kazooie). I have textured the model, rigged the model, and weight-painted the model. All is well so far. Here's where the issue comes. When I try to import it into Unity as an .obj file, it loses all texture.

That's fine because I've re-textured .obj's before and kinda expected it to happen. However, when trying to re-texture it, this happens: https://gfycat.com/IcyWillingAcornwoodpecker

How would I go about fixing this issue? Here's a screenshot of what I have in blender currently:

[image]

As I stated, I'm still quite new, so if you could be as precise in your answer as possible, that would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This looks like an issue with Unity, since it seems to display well in Blender.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be an issue with Unity

Comment: Let us not rush to close the question at this point. It was recommended to post here because it appeared to be an issue with the file, rather than Unity.   Can you upload the file to the upload site? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: That is very messed up. Did you do the unwrapping/texturing yourself? What do the UVs look like?

Comment: Here's the blender file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4401" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4401/) . I got the texture offline from this model here: https://www.models-resource.com/nintendo_64/banjotooie/model/22365/ . I just plopped the texture on my character and it worked fine. The issue was that since i'm super new to all this, the double T pose kinda threw me off and I wasn't sure if it worked the same as a normal T pose, so I just ripped my own model. At the moment, I only have one UV Map(s). https://i.imgur.com/p23Topw.png .

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie too.  Almost all tutorials I've seen using Blender and Unity together use fbx files.  I don't know why and I don't know the relative advantages or .obj and .fbx, but maybe try exporting as an fbx (on the save screen, enable mesh, armature and material only).  This should at least export the material with the mesh, making it more likely they will be compatible...maybe.

[Unity Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg5sH.png)

[image: The UVMap]

Comment: You don't even have to create the .FBX file manually. You can place the .blend in the Asset folder and let Unity control how the FBX is generated.,

Comment: When I put it into Unity as an .FBX file, this happens: https://i.imgur.com/25Ji18F.png .

Comment: Ok, here's what I've come up with, bear in mind I'm also new.

Open up your .obj in blender.  Select the mesh called "50", go to the materials panel, and scroll down until you find "Mapping".  Under "Map", choose UVMap.  In essence this is now giving Unity context on how to apply the texture.

Now export as .fbx to your project, and also bring in the material files from.  Select each material, and drag the related image file to the box left of where it says "Albedo".  Finally, select all the materials and change their Rendering Mode to Opaque.  I attached the result to my first answer.

Comment: Well, that worked haha. Not entirely sure how I messed up so hard. Would rigging the double T pose on that model yield any weird results? Or would it work just fine? Not quite sure how double T poses work.

Comment: As you say double T poses are pretty rare.  I'm barely comfortable with T poses so don't count on my answers too much.  However, from what I've read, T poses make weighting a little easier, but are more prone to strange stretching when you are in a more typical posture, and these stretch areas are at the joints, in the places that are being pulled away from.  So you can probably rig it and add weighting to it quite effectively, but you should probably tweak the weighting in a more relaxed pose, with special emphasis on the top of the shoulder and the sides of the hips.  Just my two cents :)