Noise texture baking not working
I have created one noise texture. I am trying to bake my texture, it is not working as expected. Only the color is coming in the image texture. I have attached one screenshot for reference. If I am doing it wrong, kindly guide me.


As Bake Type is set to Diffuse, the resulting image is "just" the color. Nothing wrong here for me.

@StefLAncien Kindly suggest me which type I should use. I have tried combined, emit, and roughness.

Looking at your Principal BSDF node, I guess you are looking for the Normal bake type to input the result as an Image Texture into the Bump node, instead of the Noise Texture node.

Thank you so much. It is working fine. But the default blue color is coming for the cube. When I use that image texture in Unity. Kindly guide me.

Sorry, I do not understand you last comment. And I do not know Unity...

Okay. I have baked the texture, the image is in blue color. But I want it in black color. Can we do that?

In Image Paint mode, you can paint in black to replace the blue, then save the modified image.

If I paint the image, the noise texture is not visible.

(Using Blender 4.2.0)
Setup to bake the normal map:

Setup to bake the diffuse map (all black...):

Setup to use both maps:

Resources:
(Blender 4.2.0+)

Thank you so much. It worked :).
One more query, How can I use this in Unity, The texture not coming in Unity but it is visible in Blender.

I do not use Unity, but you can have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98481/object-exported-as-obj-looses-textures-in-unity

Thank you, I will check :)
